# Knight's Tour - I can't make the knight covers the board fully

Tags: c++

**I am new to C++ and few days ago I chose Knight's Tour to practice backtracking. This program runs well when the knight doesn't have to visit each tiles, they can even miss 1 or 2 tiles and the program still works. But when it comes to the point that I have to cover the whole board, the program seems to enter infinite loop. (Yes I did tried to debug it but I still didn't figure it out)**

**Note: the starting position of the Knight is always [1; 1]**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int n, moves[100][100];

void Import()
{
    ifstream f;
    f.open("Knight's Tour.inp");
    f >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) moves[i][j] = -1;
    f.close();
}
bool If_Knight_Moves_Possible(int x, int y)
{
    return (x >= 1 && y >= 1 && x <= n && y <= n && moves[x][y] == -1);
}
bool All_Knight_Conditions_Met(int x, int y, int ways_of_x[], int ways_of_y[], int moves_count)
{
    if (moves_count > (n * n)) return(1); 
    // If you input n = 7, you minus (n * n) by 1 and the code works, for n = 8, you minus it by 2
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        long int next_x = x + ways_of_x[i], next_y = y + ways_of_y[i];
        if (If_Knight_Moves_Possible(next_x, next_y))
        {
            moves[next_x][next_y] = moves_count;
            if (All_Knight_Conditions_Met(next_x, next_y, ways_of_x, ways_of_y, moves_count + 1)) return(1);
            else moves[next_x][next_y] = -1;
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
void Analysis()
{

}
void Export()
{
    ofstream f("Knight's Tour.out");
    int ways_of_x[8] = { -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2,  2,  1 };
    int ways_of_y[8] = { -2, -1,  1,  2, 2, 1, -1, -2 };
    moves[1][1] = 1;
    if (All_Knight_Conditions_Met(1, 1, ways_of_x, ways_of_y, 2))
    {
        f << "There is a possible solution:" << endl;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
                f << setw(2) << moves[i][j] << " ";
            f << endl;
        }
    }
    else f << "There is no possible solution";
    f.close();
}
int main()
{
    Import();
    Analysis();
    Export();
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)` used as indexing when calculating `x + ways_of_x[i],` and  `y + ways_of_y[i]` will breach those arrays. They're only indexible 0..7, not 1..8. And note the grid size has nothing to do with a knight move, which is always a 1x2 move (in any of 8 trajectories). I.e. it doesn't matter whether you're on a 5x5, an 8x8, or a 50x50 board, a Knight moves 1x2 *always, and there is always exactly 8 possible trajectories to test.